# Can't change view the selected radio button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, radio-button, radio-group

[image]

I got problem with my flutter view. There's my radio button ALWAYS checked to "pria" even when radio "wanita" clicked but the value that I get work well. Here's my code:

```
class RegisterPageBio extends StatefulWidget {
  String username;
  String password;

  // receive data from the FirstScreen as a parameter
  RegisterPageBio({Key? key, required this.username, required this.password})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RegisterPageBio> createState() => _RegisterPageBioState();
}

class _RegisterPageBioState extends State<RegisterPageBio> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade50,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: _buildContent(context, widget.username, widget.password),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context, String username, String password) {
Kelamin? _gender = Kelamin.Pria;
Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                RadioListTile<Kelamin>(
                  title: const Text(
                    "Pria",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  value: Kelamin.Pria,
                  groupValue: _gender,
                  onChanged: (Kelamin? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _gender = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                RadioListTile<Kelamin>(
                  title: const Text(
                    "Wanita",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                  value: Kelamin.Wanita,
                  groupValue: _gender,
                  onChanged: (Kelamin? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _gender = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
);
```

I think that my view/frontend to create radio button. For the backend, I can handle it cause it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

On your `_buildContent()` you are declaring `_gender`  variable which is assigned to `groupValue`.

Whenever you use `setState`,  `_buildContent(...)` call and reinitialize with same value. `Kelamin? _gender = Kelamin.Pria;`.

> Dont declearing variable inside the `build` method. Put varibles outside the build method. Else it will always get the same value on every state.

```dart
class _RegisterPageBioState extends State<RegisterPageBio> {
  Kelamin? _gender = Kelamin.Pria;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade50,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: _buildContent(context, widget.username, widget.password),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context, String username, String password
      ) {
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: scope issue, try update answer